# Transform bidimensional array in a multidimensional depth array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Javascript array like this:

```
[
    "values": [
        "Gray",
        "Beige",
        "Black"
    ],  
    "values": [
        "Large",
        "Small",
        "Medium"
    ]
]
```

and, I need to transform it in the following:

```
[
    "Gray": [
        "Large": 0,
        "Small": 0,
        "Medium": 0
    ],
    "Beige": [
        "Large": 0,
        "Small": 0,
        "Medium": 0
    ],
    "Black": [
        "Large": 0,
        "Small": 0,
        "Medium": 0
    ]:
]
```

The main complexity is that the first array can have many `values` arrays, and I need its values **become to the indexes** of the new array, **depthly**. I am sure this can be make using a loop structure, but I am tired of trying.

I accept any solution for this, using Javascript and/or jQuery code :).

Comment: Please show what you tried that didn't work. This isn't a free code writing service. The idea here is for us to help fix ***your code***

Comment: you don't have an array like this. it is just no array, nor object.

Comment: This is not a valid JavaScript array. JavaScript arrays cannot have keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all both arrays are invalid. You cannot have keys in an array in JavaScript.

Youre looking for either an object or a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Ma)

So your second invalid array would be valid with being an object within an object:

```
{
    Gray:{
        Large: 0,
        Small: 0,
        Medium: 0
    },
    Beige:{
        Large: 0,
        Small: 0,
        Medium: 0
    },
    Black: {
        Large: 0,
        Small: 0,
        Medium: 0
    }:
}
```

Problem is that, iterating over a javascript object is not simple and is not prefered for that case.

So i would go for a Map inside your first level array like so

```
var myMap = new Map();

var keyString = 'Gray'

// setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, { Large:0, Small:0, Medium:0 });
```

And then you can loop over your map with a for of

```
for (var [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value);
}
```

Please checkout the [Map Docs from MDN for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Thanks, this is a very useful answer.

Comment: My pleasure, if you find it answered your question, i invite you to mark it as the selected answer ! :)